# tidyr::expand get names of tibble as variables to expand?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I am looking for more generic expansion of data.frame (table or tibble). The code will explain better what I mean. This is when I expand dt by `mean` and `sd` columns.

```
dt <- tibble::tibble(
  mean = c(10,20,30),
  sd = c(1,2,3),
  median = c(3,4,5)
) 
dt %>% tidyr::expand(., mean, sd)
```

I am searching something more generic, like this one, which is not working:

```
dt %>% tidyr::expand(., list("mean", "sd"))
```

Even where I can specify more complicated logic on expansion (also not working):

```
exp.cols <- dt %>% names(.) %>% .[stringr::str_detect(., "d")]
dt %>% tidyr::expand(., exp.cols)
```

Data could came from external place, so there is no option to filter then do expand on all columns.

Comment: Wrap it with syms `dt %>% tidyr::expand(., !!! rlang::syms(list("mean", "sd")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to convert to symbols (`syms`) and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  tidyr::expand(!!! rlang::syms(list("mean", "sd")))
```

---

Or use the column names

```
dt %>% 
  tidyr::expand(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[1:2]))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#   mean    sd
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1    10     1
#2    10     2
#3    10     3
#4    20     1
#5    20     2
#6    20     3
#7    30     1
#8    30     2
#9    30     3
```